# how do I relocate a working-copy from tag to branch?

Tags: svn, tags, branch

I checked out code from a tag, applied some fixes but now I have to check that into some branch. How do I do this, can I use svn relocate after I `svn copy`-ied the tag to a new working branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked out code from a tag, applied some fixes but now I have to
>   check that into some branch.

There is a chance that you will have to rework your code modifications as there will be merge or switch conflicts. You should not work on tags, but create a branch first and make your modifications in that branch.

Anyway, try this:

1. Make a backup of your working copy with local uncommitted modifications (just to be on the safe side of the street).
2. Branch from trunk or another repository subtree.
3. Switch your working copy with local uncommitted modifications the new branch.
4. Resolve merge conflicts if any.
5. Commit your changes to the branch.

And don't forget to read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). :)

Comment: yes, I realized I had made a mistake, anyways, I was able to grab the files changed, and copy them to a fresh checked out branch..! I didn't have to go through what you suggested.... but Thanks anyways!